# Composer neither installing nor updating RecursiveDirectoryIterator Cannot find path specified

Tags: composer-php

I have been trying to update / install with composer on my windows7  64 bit machine. But lately I am getting this errors:

```
$ php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing zendframework/zendxml (dev-master 559b34f)
    Cloning 559b34f426d33a11c3db118e00ce14bb8dc64e5f
Failed to download zendframework/zendxml from source: RecursiveDirectoryIterator
::__construct(C:\wamp\www\projects\vendor\zendframework\zendxml,C:\wamp\www\projects\vendor\zendframework\zendxml): The system cannot find the path specified. (
code: 3)
Now trying to download from dist
  - Installing zendframework/zendxml (dev-master 559b34f)
    Downloading: 100%



  [UnexpectedValueException]
  RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(C:\wamp\www\projects\vendor/zendfra
  mework/zendxml,C:\wamp\www\projects\vendor/zendframework/zendxml): The syst
  em cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)
```

I have tried to remove the vendor directory as well as empty the composer cache but this didn't solve the issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that I moved a directory which enabled colors in cmd.exe. Now the directory was not linked properly anymore.

Check out https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-windows- and also check for invalid paths.

Comment: I had the same issue after previously installing Ansicon. The trick of removing the Autorun entry from under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a write permisions error in the vendor's folder.

Stop Apache and delete the folder /vendor/zendframework and run again composer install.